# How to add two views on each other with constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add 2 views with same X, Y. They have space from the edge using `addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat...]`

I tried the strings `"H:|20-[A][B]-20-[C]-20-[D]-20|"` and `V:|20-[A][B]-20-[C]-20-[D]-20|`, and `centreX == CenterX` and `centerY==centerY`, but they kept conflicting, thinking that A and B should be next to each other.

A is hidden, and on some button clicked, B is hidden and A is shown.

Comment: Do you want the two views to overlap each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add views with same centre X,Y You need to first place one of the view say bView (Bottom view), using constatins

```
NSArray * bVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[bView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView)];
    NSArray * bHorizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[bView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView)];
```

This places the bView in the superview with 20 as edge offset.

Now place the tView (top View) with same centre as of bView. Here self is the superview of bView and tView

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bView]-(<=1)-[tView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView,tView)]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[bView]-(<=1)-[tView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView,tView)]];
```

Then pin the edges of tView with desired offset say 40

```
NSArray * tVerticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-40-[tView]-40-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tView)];
    NSArray * tHorizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-40-[tView]-40-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tView)];
```

EDIT :

Here is how do do it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    bView = [UIView new];
    bView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    tView = [UIView new];
    tView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // Firdt bView is added then tView hence tView is exaclty above the bView.
    [self.view addSubview:bView];
    [self.view addSubview:tView];


    // Edges Constrints for bView
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[bView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[bView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView)]];

    // Edges Constints for tView
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[tView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[tView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tView)]];

    // Centring for bView and tView
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[bView]-(<=1)-[tView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView,tView)]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[bView]-(<=1)-[tView]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bView,tView)]];

}

-(IBAction)toggleViews:(id)sender {
    NSArray * subViews = self.view.subviews;
    [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:[subViews indexOfObject:tView] withSubviewAtIndex:[subViews indexOfObject:bView]];
}
```

Comment: it doesn't look like to be working, i edited my question to make my self clearer,  in your case, i want viewT is hidden at first, and at some point viewB will be shown

Comment: @shd So you want A initially then on some button click B (with same size and position as A) visually replaces A?